# json element undefined in render method in react.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a render problem, in `componentDidMount` I use axios for a get call, I assign the response data using `setState`.

The problem is: when I try to access response data in `render`, they are undefined, because `componentDidMount` works after `render`...

For example:

```js
export default class ShowDetails extends Component { 
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props); 
        this.accountService=new AccountService(); 
        this.state = { 
            account:[] 
        }     
    } 

    componentDidMount() { 
        this.accountService.getAccount().then(r => this.setState({ account: r.data })); 
    } 

    render() { 
        return ( {this.state.account.all.moneyavailable.Formatted} //this is undefined
```

I have alredy tried to move in other place the axios call, but without success

the json:

```js
{
  "account": [{
      "saldoDisponibileFormatted": "1.664,57",
      "saldoContabileFormatted": "1.341,10",
      "value": "EUR",
      "debit": false,
      "productAlias": null,
      "bank": "bank",
      "iban": "IT31M0326801017052670700860",
      "moviments": [{
          "causShort": "Commissioni",
          "import": "1,00",
          "sign": "D"
        },

      ],
      "dateUpdate1": "n/d",
      "dateUpdate2": "4/12/2018"
    },

  ],
  "all": {
    "moneyavailable": {
      "Formatted": "1950,82"
    },
    "moneyavailable2": {
      "Formatted": "31627,35"
    },
    "dateUpdate": "4/12/2018"
  }
}
```

Comment: The "JSON" you posted is not [JSON](http://json.org). It is probably a JavaScript object and this is a completely different thing than JSON. JSON is a text representation of some data structure (that can be an object, an array, a string, a number or a boolean).

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition in render.

```
  render() { return ( {this.state.account.length && this.state.account.all.moneyavailable.Formatted}
```

Comment: length is 0 in console log, and the value is undefined

Comment: render calls everytime whenever any change made. so first time it will give length 0 then once componentDidMount update state length become > 0 and `this.state.account.all.moneyavailable.Formatted` will execute.

Answer (score 0):

@L.Mantega Your are using promise method, It may take some time to resolve after execution of did mount method, so i made some example code  and am able to see the data render method.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) { 
super(props); 
this.state = { account:[] } 
} 
componentDidMount()
{
this.getAccount().then(x=> this.setState({account:x}));
}
getAccount()
{
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  let data = [
    {
        "saldoDisponibileFormatted": "1.664,57",
        "saldoContabileFormatted": "1.341,10",
        "value": "EUR",
        "debit": false,
        "productAlias": null,
        "bank": "bank",
        "iban": "IT31M0326801017052670700860",
        "moviments": [
            {
                "causShort": "Commissioni",
                "import": "1,00",
                "sign": "D"
            },

        ],
        "dateUpdate1": "n/d",
        "dateUpdate2": "4/12/2018"
    }
];
    resolve(data);
  }, 300);
});
}
  render() {
    return <div>{(this.state.account.length > 0) ? this.state.account[0]["saldoDisponibileFormatted"]:"checking for data " }</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: How to pass my json without writing it?

Comment: you can still use the same line -> this.accountService.getAccount().then(r => this.setState({ account: r.data }));    for demo purpose i used static data, just log and  verify r.data inside "then" block

Answer (score 0):

```
 getConti() {
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         setTimeout(function() {
             const URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_PATH+process.env.REACT_APP_RESOURCE_CONTI;
             console.log(URL);
             return   axios(URL, {

                 method: 'GET',
                 headers: {
                     'content-type': 'application/json',
                     'preferences' : ''
                 }}
             )
             resolve();
         }, 300);
     });
 }
}
```